# pyGTK Radio Button

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Alright, I'll preface this with the fact that I'm a GTK *and* Python newb, but I haven't been able to dig up the information I needed. Basically what I have is a list of Radio Buttons, and based on which one is checked, I need to connect a button to a different function. I tried creating all my radio buttons, and then creating a disgusting if/else block checking for `sget_active()` on each button. The problem is the same button returns true every single time. Any ideas?

Here's the code in use:

```
    #Radio Buttons Center
    self.updatePostRadioVBox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
    self.updatePageRadio = gtk.RadioButton(None, "Updating Page")
    self.updatePostRadio = gtk.RadioButton(self.updatePageRadio, "Updating Blog Post")
    self.pageRadio = gtk.RadioButton(self.updatePageRadio, "New Page")
    self.blogRadio = gtk.RadioButton(self.updatePageRadio, "New Blog Post")
    self.addSpaceRadio = gtk.RadioButton(self.updatePageRadio, "Add New Space")
    self.removePageRadio = gtk.RadioButton(self.updatePageRadio, "Remove Page")
    self.removePostRadio = gtk.RadioButton(self.updatePageRadio, "Remove Blog Post")
    self.removeSpaceRadio = gtk.RadioButton(self.updatePageRadio, "Remove Space")


    #Now the buttons to direct us from here
    self.returnMainMenuButton = gtk.Button(" Main Menu ")
    self.returnMainMenuButton.connect("clicked", self.transToMain)
    self.contentManageHBoxBottom.pack_start(self.returnMainMenuButton, False, False, 30)
    self.contentProceedButton = gtk.Button("    Proceed    ")
    self.contentManageHBoxBottom.pack_end(self.contentProceedButton, False, False, 30)

    if self.updatePageRadio.get_active():
        self.contentProceedButton.connect("clicked", self.updatePage)

    elif self.updatePostRadio.get_active():
        self.contentProceedButton.connect("clicked", self.updatePost)

    elif self.pageRadio.get_active():
        self.contentProceedButton.connect("clicked", self.newPage)

    elif self.blogRadio.get_active():
        self.contentProceedButton.connect("clicked", self.newBlogPost)

    elif self.addSpaceRadio.get_active():
        self.contentProceedButton.connect("clicked", self.newSpace)

    elif self.removePageRadio.get_active():
        self.contentProceedButton.connect("clicked", self.removePage)

    elif self.removePostRadio.get_active():
        self.contentProceedButton.connect("clicked", self.removeBlogPost)

    elif self.removeSpaceRadio.get_active():
        self.contentProceedButton.connect("clicked", self.removeSpace)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: (since you posted some code), just use:

```
active = [r for r in self.updatePageRadio.get_group() if r.get_active()][0]
```

and use that to look up in a dict of functions and call it:

```
my_actions[active]()
```

---

Edit: I totally forgot to mention that this is not a good use-case at all for RadioButtons, regular gtk.Button would be much better in my opinion.

---

Your answer is to use the RadioButton "groups" system. It is explained in [this document](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkradiobutton.html), but here is a small practical example.

Firstly a group is really just a RadioButton itself that is used to collect a number of other RadioButtons. You specify a group as the first argument to the constructor.

```
r1 = gtk.RadioButton(None, label='Cat') # this has no group, it is the first
r2 = gtk.RadioButton(r1, label='Mouse') # use the first radio
                                        # button as the group argument
r3 = gtk.RadioButton(r1, label='Dog')   # again use r1
```

Now all the radio buttons will be synchronised. And the matter of reading them is as easy as:

```
active_radios = [r for r in r1.get_group() if r.get_active()]
```

Comment: You're right. Buttons are the way to go. Thanks for clearing my stupidity, and for the lessons on radio buttons!

Comment: But if one wants index in RadioButton group system designed only one active at a time, then one may do `active_radios = [int(i) for i,r in enumerate(reversed(r1.get_group())) if r.get_active()]`. Then `active_radios[0]` should give necessary index.

Answer (score 0):

First, I presume that's a typo and you're actually calling get_active() in your code and not set_active()? Other than that, without seeing the code, I can point you to a pygtk tutorial about [radio buttons](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-RadioButtons.html)